# RedHawk v2.1 Device IDL Error

Tags: redhawksdr

We have using RedHawk v2.1 on Xynq7035 ARM COretex A9 with Embedded Linux kernel 3.14. Our application is SSB Tx/Rx SDR. So waveforms consist of 3 types, one is SSB RX, two is SSB TX, three is CW TX. The HW device has 6 dataFloat ports and 6 dataUlong ports, each with a total of 12 ports. Start up procedure is below.

```
#nodeBooter -D &
#nodeBooter -d /usr/lib/redhawk/sdr/dev/nodes/dev_trx_node/DeviceManager.dcd.xml &
#rh_start.py &
```

rh_start.py code is below.

```
from ossie.utils import redhawk
import logging
logging.basicConfig()
domain_list = redhawk.scan()
dom = redhawk.attach(domain_list[0])
wave0 = dom.createApplication("/waveforms/rx_waveform/rx_waveform.sad.xml")
dom.devices[1].connect(wave0.comps[0], usesPortName='out_data_rx', providesPortName='in_data' )
```

The error is occered when connecting the device and waveform port. Error code is

```
ERROR:ossie.utils.model:Invalid port descriptor in scd for IDL:BULKIO/dataFloat:1.0
ERROR:ossie.utils.model:Invalid port descriptor in scd for IDL:BULKIO/dataFloat:1.0
ERROR:ossie.utils.model:Invalid port descriptor in scd for IDL:BULKIO/dataFloat:1.0
ERROR:ossie.utils.model:Invalid port descriptor in scd for IDL:BULKIO/dataUlong:1.0
ERROR:ossie.utils.model:Invalid port descriptor in scd for IDL:BULKIO/dataUlong:1.0
ERROR:ossie.utils.model:Invalid port descriptor in scd for IDL:BULKIO/dataUlong:1.0
ERROR:ossie.utils.model:Invalid port descriptor in scd for IDL:BULKIO/dataFloat:1.0
ERROR:ossie.utils.model:Invalid port descriptor in scd for IDL:BULKIO/dataFloat:1.0
ERROR:ossie.utils.model:Invalid port descriptor in scd for IDL:BULKIO/dataFloat:1.0
ERROR:ossie.utils.model:Invalid port descriptor in scd for IDL:BULKIO/dataUlong:1.0
ERROR:ossie.utils.model:Invalid port descriptor in scd for IDL:BULKIO/dataUlong:1.0
ERROR:ossie.utils.model:Invalid port descriptor in scd for IDL:BULKIO/dataUlong:1.0
ERROR:ossie.utils.model:Unable to find port description for IDL:CF/Port:1.0
ERROR:ossie.utils.model:Invalid port descriptor in scd for IDL:ExtendedEvent/MessageEvent:1.0enter code here
```

The error is on all the ports of my device and all ports of GPP. My device is created with RedHawk-IDE v2.1. GPP downloads v2.1 and cross-compiles. GPP.scd.xml has no changed. Is the scd.xml file wrong? our device ports section in scd.xml file is below.

```
<ports>
  <provides repid="IDL:BULKIO/dataFloat:1.0" providesname="in_data_cw">
    <porttype type="data"/>
  </provides>
  <uses repid="IDL:BULKIO/dataFloat:1.0" usesname="out_data_cw">
    <porttype type="data"/>
  </uses>
  <provides repid="IDL:BULKIO/dataFloat:1.0" providesname="in_data_rx">
    <porttype type="data"/>
  </provides>
  <uses repid="IDL:BULKIO/dataFloat:1.0" usesname="out_data_rx">
    <porttype type="data"/>
  </uses>
  <provides repid="IDL:BULKIO/dataFloat:1.0" providesname="in_data_tx">
    <porttype type="data"/>
  </provides>
  <uses repid="IDL:BULKIO/dataFloat:1.0" usesname="out_data_tx">
    <porttype type="data"/>
  </uses>
  <provides repid="IDL:BULKIO/dataUlong:1.0" providesname="in_cnt_cw">
    <porttype type="data"/>
  </provides>
  <uses repid="IDL:BULKIO/dataUlong:1.0" usesname="out_cnt_cw">
    <porttype type="data"/>
  </uses>
  <provides repid="IDL:BULKIO/dataUlong:1.0" providesname="in_cnt_rx">
    <porttype type="data"/>
  </provides>
  <uses repid="IDL:BULKIO/dataUlong:1.0" usesname="out_cnt_rx">
    <porttype type="data"/>
  </uses>
  <provides repid="IDL:BULKIO/dataUlong:1.0" providesname="in_cnt_tx">
    <porttype type="data"/>
  </provides>
  <uses repid="IDL:BULKIO/dataUlong:1.0" usesname="out_cnt_tx">
    <porttype type="data"/>
  </uses>
</ports>
```

The application itself works, but could you tell us the cause of the error and the workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems `IDL:BULKIO/dataFloat:1.0` is not present in the IDL library according to the line [1266 of model module init](https://github.com/RedhawkSDR/framework-core/blob/master/src/base/framework/python/ossie/utils/model/__init__.py#L1266). Check if IDL library exists in the path: `$OSSIEHOME/share/idl`. also check if your scd file has something like:

```
<interface name="ProvidesPortStatisticsProvider" repid="IDL:BULKIO/ProvidesPortStatisticsProvider:1.0"/>
    <interface name="updateSRI" repid="IDL:BULKIO/updateSRI:1.0"/>
    <interface name="dataFloat" repid="IDL:BULKIO/dataFloat:1.0">
      <inheritsinterface repid="IDL:BULKIO/ProvidesPortStatisticsProvider:1.0"/>
      <inheritsinterface repid="IDL:BULKIO/updateSRI:1.0"/>
    </interface>
```

inside the interfaces tag.

a tip: ports can use core-framework IDLs, besides `IDL:BULKIO`, you can use `IDL:CF/Resource` to control a component, `IDL:CF/Device` to control a Device. you are even able to get a reference of the Domain using ports. This way, you can create a single waveform for the SSB (TX and RX) implemeting a proper Assembly controller, to dictate the way your waveform works.

Are you using a ADRV9361 (picozed sdr)? if so... you could evaluate my FrontEnd Device [AD936X_LIBIIO](https://github.com/rodrigo455/AD936X_LIBIIO)... how did you embed (cross compiled) in Zynq REDHAWK?

Comment: We are using own SCA Device. Our evaluation board is own design using Zynq7035. HW interface driver too. Compiling environment is YOCTO project.

Comment: Are you familiar with GeonTech's work? they provide a [redhawk meta layer for yocto](https://github.com/Geontech/meta-redhawk-sdr/).  Look at [this line](https://github.com/RedhawkSDR/framework-core/blob/master/src/base/framework/python/ossie/utils/model/__init__.py#L51) It looks for IDL lib in the OSSIEHOME path. That might be the issue.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I mistake symbolic link from /usr/share to /usr/lib/redhawk/core/share. When i do correct link, Error is disapeared. Heavy thanks.

Answer (score 0):

IDL Library exists in /usr/share/idl/ossie/BULKIO Is not $OSSIEHOME/share/idl, but bio_daraUlog_idl.py and bio_dataFloat_idl.py are in $OSSIEHOME/lib/python/bulkio/bulkioInterface . I'm sorry to forgot discribe "from bulkio.bulkioInterface import BULKIO" . however above errors are occuerd without this import description. 
My scd file's interface tags are:

```
<interfaces>
...............
    <interface name="dataFloat" repid="IDL:BULKIO/dataFloat:1.0">
      <inheritsinterface repid="IDL:BULKIO/ProvidesPortStatisticsProvider:1.0"/>
      <inheritsinterface repid="IDL:BULKIO/updateSRI:1.0"/>
    </interface>
    <interface name="ProvidesPortStatisticsProvider" repid="IDL:BULKIO/ProvidesPortStatisticsProvider:1.0"/>
    <interface name="updateSRI" repid="IDL:BULKIO/updateSRI:1.0"/>
    <interface name="dataUlong" repid="IDL:BULKIO/dataUlong:1.0">
      <inheritsinterface repid="IDL:BULKIO/ProvidesPortStatisticsProvider:1.0"/>
      <inheritsinterface repid="IDL:BULKIO/updateSRI:1.0"/>
    </interface>
</interfaces>
```

I think that included your pointed out.